# Jquery events for dragging missing?

Tags: events

I see examples like this.

```
windowId.bind( 'dragstart'....
```

but looking for drag events in here don't exist. 
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Also when I run examples the events don't fires. So I'm obviously missing something here. If drag, dragstart, dragover, ect are not jquery events what are they?

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop events are not events Native jQuery, you have to use a plugin. I recommend this:
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: I may try that next, I'm try to get this code to work on mvc http://jsfiddle.net/5r3Eh/10/show/  and need the documentation for it.

Comment: The demo are using http://threedubmedia.com drag plugin.
access the site and see the documentation.

Comment: Just a handy tip - with jsfiddle urls, if you drop the `/show` you can [see how it was set up](http://jsfiddle.net/5r3Eh/10/)... You'll note that under "External resources" it's referencing http://threedubmedia.googlecode.com/files/jquery.event.drag-1.5.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean jQuery UI's drag and drop events? [Here is something about it](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events).

Comment: actually that comment help a great deal. Looks like I'm after this threedubmedia.googlecode.com/files/jquery.event.drag-1.5.min.js